# How to permanently add the new installation Puppet directory to the ruby LOAD_PATH on RHEL7?

Tags: ruby, puppet, rhel

The puppet installation was successful but the command

```
sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

resulted in the error:

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- puppet/util/command_line (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /bin/puppet:7:in `<main>'
```

As I understand the new puppet installation directory /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ is not in the ruby LOAD_PATH.

I tried manually change the LOAD_PATH using ruby -I or LOAD_PATH.unshift or RUBYLIB.  All of this did not result into the permanent change of LOAD_PATH, only the temporary change happened.

The directories in the LOAD_PATH are ["/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/share/rubygems", "/usr/share/ruby", "/usr/lib64/ruby/"]

Comment: What version of Puppet have you installed?  No remotely recent version supports Ruby 1.8, or should be installed in such a directory.  The latest (fresh off the presses today) is Puppet 6.0.  Puppet 4 and 5 are both pretty common.  Puppet 3 persists, but should not be used for new installations, and I'm not sure whether even it supports Puppet 1.8.

Comment: I use "yum install puppet". Downloading packages: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch.rpm

Comment: I urge you to instead choose a modern version of Puppet.  v6.0 is a little too fresh for my personal taste, though; I would choose v5.5.  Puppet, Inc. provides appropriate yum repositories, and ample documentation on how to install Puppet from them.  Start [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/puppet_platform.html).